# Codility Flags Challenge Time Complexity Explanation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I recently attempted the [Codility Flags challenge](https://app.codility.com/programmers/task/flags/).  Unfortunately I couldn’t figure out the O(n) solution for myself so had to refer to their [solution PDF](https://codility.com/media/train/solution-flags.pdf).  I’ve slightly adjusted their implementation to make it more readable to me, resulting in the following solution:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    var N = A.Length;
    if (N < 3)
        return 0;
    var peaks = CalculatePeaks(A, N);
    var nextPeaks = CalculateNextPeaks(peaks, N);
    var maxNumFlagsSet = 0;
    var peaksCount = peaks.Count(p => p);
    for (var i = 1; i <= peaksCount; ++i)
    {
        var pos = 0;
        var numFlagsSet = 0;
        while (pos < N && numFlagsSet < i)
        {
            pos = nextPeaks[pos];
            if (pos == -1)
                break;
            numFlagsSet += 1;
            pos += i;
        }

        maxNumFlagsSet = Math.Max(maxNumFlagsSet, numFlagsSet);
    }

    return maxNumFlagsSet;
}
```

I understand the correctness of the above implementation but I don’t understand why the complexity of the solution algorithm is O(n).  Specifically the following nested loops:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= peaksCount; ++i)
{
    var pos = 0;
    var numFlagsSet = 0;
    while (pos < N && numFlagsSet < i)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

To offer my (limited) understanding: the upper-bound on `peaksCount` is `√N`, so the outer loop will be executed at most `√N` times, but what can we reason about how many times the inner `while` loop will be executed?  Or perhaps this reasoning is heading down completely the wrong path and someone can offer a simpler explanation of the O(n) complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop runs at most up to `i` times per outer loop. So, if the outer loop runs from 0 to `√N`, then on the first outer iteration, the inner loop runs one time, then 2, then 3, etc. 
It is a commonly known and important fact in computer science that the sum of 1 to `n` is `n(n+1)/2`. That is, if you had a for loop from 1 to `n`, and you summed up `i`, you'd get `n(n+1)/2`. Therefore, the inner loop (which runs 1, 2, 3.. `√N`) runs a total of `√N*(√N+1)/2`, which is `O(√N^2)` or `O(N)`